# How to split up Date and Time into two separate columns in R markdown

Tags: r, time

[image]

Ok so I'm trying to split up the Time into another column that has the date. What code can I use to do that in R markdown? I'm very new to R so please explain simply! Can I somehow use a function to continue this line of code that got me the data set in the picture:

`turtle <- turtle %>%
  rename(HeartRate = m.HR) %>%
  select("Time", "Turtle", "HeartRate")`

Please help!

Comment: Hi! It is difficult to reproduce your problem without having a little excerpt of your data, what we call [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you can put the first lines of `turtles` data frame we could help you with much more quality.

Comment: `turtle %>% mutate(date = as.Date(Time))`?

Comment: Your problem, at least to me, doesn't seem to be a RMarkdown problem. You probably should split the Time info into two columns before knitting to RMarkdown. There are several ways to do that but with your code being posted we could give you more assertive answers.

Comment: You can use `tidyr separate` the [documentation](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) will help with edge cases. here, you may want to try `turtle %>% separate(Time, c=("Date","Time"), " ")` I agree with rdornas that this is not an RMarkdown problem but a data problem.

Comment: @jessi, after looking up the function separate, I got the columns to split. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Super. Please post your solution as the answer to help future users @Cassidy

Answer (score 0):

```
turtle <- separate(turtle, Time, into = c("Date", "Time"), " ")
```

The above code is what I used to separate the one column into two.